# Why does Java resize a Window to 1x1 pixel when HDMI is unplugged (and does not resize back when HDMI is plugged)

Tags: java, linux, wayland, weston, xwayland

I have a Java application running on:

XWayland 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u6,
Weston 9.0.0-1,
OpenJDK 11.0.18+10-1~deb11u1,
Debian 11,
Kernel 5.10.52

My JFrame (Window) is set to: `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);`

I can then see my interface on the full screen (in my case it is a TV and I have CEC enabled in the Kernel). However, after I unplug HDMI and plug HDMI again, my interface is gone (black screen). There is only one small 1x1 pixel left. It seems the size of the Window is changed by Java / XWayland / (Weston). I am sure, that I am not changing it - I check all resize methods on JFrame.

When I restart my Java application, it is back again - so it is not an issue of the OS (Linux) directly and also - most probably - not Weston.

I also don't have this issue with a pure Wayland application (e.g. Weston flower). Using only Wayland (without Java and XWayland) things work.

When I PLUG the HDMI there is NO java.awt.event.ComponentEvent

When I UNPLUG HDMI, I get the following java.awt.event.ComponentEvent:

```
java.awt.event.ComponentEvent[COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 1x1)] on frame0
java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1602)
java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentResized(AWTEventMulticaster.java:167)
java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentResized(AWTEventMulticaster.java:167)
java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6461)
java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6415)
java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2049)
java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Unfortunately I also don't know how to manipulate the size after I catched this event. I tried to directly set the size back, but this did not work. I think it may don't work because at this time HDMI is UNPLUGGED.

As I don't get any event when the HDMI is PLUGGED again, I also don't know when to (try to) set the size back to "normal".